# How many nonnegative integer solutions to equation $x_1 + x_2 + x_3 + x_4 = n$ if $x_2 + x_4 \geq 3$?

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Please determine the number of solutions to the equation

$$x_1 + x_2 + x_3 + x_4 = n$$

where $x_i,n \in \mathbb{N} \cup \{0\}$,  $x_2 + x_4 \geq 3$?

Comment: These are infinites if there is no condition on $n$

Comment: Just take two values whose sum is greater than $3$ and other three can be choosen randomly

Comment: Do you perhaps want the number of solutions for a given $n$?

Comment: What have you attempted?  Where are you stuck?  Please edit your question to include this information rather than placing it in the comments or answers.

Answer (score 2):

Suppose $n\ge 3$. Fix $x_2+x_4=k$, with $k \in [3,n]$ which can be done $k+1$ ways. Then you have to find the number of solution of $x_1+x_3=n-k$ which can be done in $n-k+1$ wyas. Therefore in total we have
\begin{align}
\sum_{k=3}^{n}(k+1)(n-k+1)&=\sum_{k=4}^{n+1}k(n+2-k)\\
&=\left(-6(n+2)+(n+2)\sum_{k=1}^{n+1}k\right)-\left(-14+\sum_{k=1}^{n+1}k^2\right)\\
&=2-6n+(n+2)\frac{(n+1)(n+2)}{2}-\frac{(n+1)(n+2)(2n+3)}{6}\\
&=2-6n+\frac{(n+1)(n+2)(n+3)}{6}\\
&=2-6n+\binom{n+3}{3}.
\end{align}

Answer (score 1):

By adding 4, then we think positive integer solution. change $x_2+x_4→x_3+x_4$. 
For example $n=4$, minimum solution is $(1,1,1,4)(1,1,2,3)(1,1,3,2)(1,1,4,1)$. 
Since exceptions are $(x_3,x_4)=(1,3)(2,2)(3,1),(1,2)(2,1),(1,1)$,

$_{n+3}C_3-3*_{n-1}C_1-2*_{n}C_1-_{n+1}C_{1}$

$=(n+1)(n+2)(n+3)/6-6n+2$

$=\dfrac{n^3+6n^2-25n+18}{6}$